# Best way to call a function from laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I am integrating google translate in my app in laravel and has code like this in my blade files

```
 <h3>{{GoogleTranslate::justTranslate($tagline, session()->get('lang'))}}</h3>
```

I want to write a function somewhere where I can check if the language is english and return text without translation if so.

I tried writing blade directives like this

```
 Blade::directive('language', function ($expression) {
     $lang = session()->get('lang');
     $out = $expression;
     if ($lang != "" && $lang != "en") {
       $out = GoogleTranslate::justTranslate($expression, session()->get('lang'));
     }
     return $out;
 });
```

Here the issue is instead of the content of variable the variable name is being passed into $expression.

Is directives the right way to do this or helper functions?

Comment: can i access session variables there?

Comment: maybe you can use $$myvar  to get the content of the myvar name. ie if $myvar="var2", and $var2="hello" $$myvar is "hello".